# Docker image creation (weblogic and java)

Tags: linux, docker, weblogic, dockerfile

I need to create an image which must include weblogic(10.3.6) and java(1.8). I have written a dockerfile which I face an error. I need to know the image script to build this perticular image. I have shared my dockerfile content but not sure whether it is right since I am facing the below error

```
/bin/sh: /bin/tar: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/tar -zxvf /home/docuser/myimages/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Request to help me in building the fresh docker image or help me in modifying the dockerfile created below

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
WORKDIR /home/docuser/myimages/
ADD . /home/docuser/myimages/
RUN /bin/tar -zxvf /home/docuser/myimages/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN /home/docuser/myimages/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java -jar wls1036_generic.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Still, we should reference docs of Docker. There is a [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) about Dockerfile.

> Consequently, the best use for ADD is local tar file auto-extraction into the image, as in ADD rootfs.tar.xz /.

That means you could just use the only instruction below:

```
ADD jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz  /home/docuser/myimages/
```

To answer your question, I put the whole Dockerfile below.

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
ADD jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz /home/docuser/myimages
COPY wls1036_generic.jar /home/docuser/myimages
WORKDIR /home/docuser/myimages
RUN chmod u+x /home/docuser/myimages/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/*
RUN /home/docuser/myimages/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java -jar wls1036_generic.jar
```

Comment: Not his problem, he need install tar and gzip

Comment: @Pacolotero No, he needn't. I've tried that on my own machine.

Answer (score 0):

The docker image `oraclelinux:7-slim` does not have the essential packages installed.

Yo need install `tar` and `gzip` before executing the "targz" command:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
RUN yum install -y tar gzip
WORKDIR /home/docuser/myimages/
ADD . /home/docuser/myimages/
RUN /bin/tar xvzf /home/docuser/myimages/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
```